Swinject Dependencies not being properly initialized: Swinject: Resolution failed
I'm having an issue when trying to initialize my dependencies via a container using Swinject. I get the error:

Swinject: Resolution failed. Expected registration:
{ Service: LoginViewModel, Factory: Resolver -> LoginViewModel }
Available registrations:
MyApp/MyApp.swift:29: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Not sure what the issue could be. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
DIController.swift:
import Swinject
import Supabase

class DIContainer {
    static let shared = DIContainer()
    let container: Container

    private init() {
        container = Container()
    }

    func initializeDependencies() async {
        container.register(LoginViewModel.self) { resolver in
            LoginViewModel(supabaseClient: supabaseClient)
        }
    }
}

MyApp.swift
import SwiftUI
import Swinject
import SwiftData

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    init() {

        // Initialize dependencies
        Task {
            await DIContainer.shared.initializeDependencies()
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(DIContainer.shared.container.resolve(LoginViewModel.self)!)
        }
    }
}


The crash is because you force unwrapped the result of resolve.  The root cause is that you are calling initializeDependencies asynchronously, so at the time you try and resolve the dependency it hasn't yet been registered. Why are you using a Task?

My bad. You are right. Calling initializeDependencies asynchronously was the issue. Also removed the Task. Thank you!

You have wrapped your call to DIContainer.shared.initializeDependencies() in a Task.  This means that it will complete asynchronously.
As a result, the dependencies are not yet registered when you call DIContainer.shared.container.resolve(LoginViewModel.self). Since you force unwrap the result of this call you get a crash.
There is no need for initializeDependencies to be declared async. Remove this declaration and then you won't need the Task.
Also, it should be noted that singletons are an anti-pattern in general and a specific anti-pattern that DI is intended to address. It is ironic that you have used a singleton for your DI container.  You don't need to do this.

Thank you for your help. I'm pretty new to iOS development and especially using DI in iOS. Do you have any resources you could point me to for proper DI practices? The one I followed was using this singleton approach
